# print from html form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this form:

```
name....
amount....
remaining....
[submit]
```

I am using the following code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="name">name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="amount">Amount</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" placeholder="$" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Remaining">Remaining</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="Remaining" name="Remaining" type="text" placeholder="$" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="singlebutton">Submit</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I expect the result like this:

```
customer (name) has submitted (20$). remaining amount is (30$)
```

How can I get this with out using PHP/CGI etc and only JavaScript. Preferably in a new window with a print button.

Comment: not sure which javascript i would use.

Comment: which javascript??, how many you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed "form" tag, because i assume we will use only client programming, so form submission is not needed. this script below may help you.

```
<fieldset>
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="name">name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="amount">Amount</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" placeholder="$" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Remaining">Remaining</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="Remaining" name="Remaining" type="text" placeholder="$" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="singlebutton">Submit</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submit();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

<div id="info"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function submit()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        var remaining = document.getElementById("Remaining").value;

        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "customer ("+name+") has submitted ("+amount+"$). remaining amount is ("+remaining+"$)"; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[0].style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: awesome...can i get output in a new page. or same page but hide the form

Comment: is it possible that, on submit, the form disappears and only the output is shown on that same page...thanks

Comment: sory for long response i was on holiday 2 days ago. :).

if you want to hide form hide the fieldset element.

 i'll edit my code above so the form will hide while press submit. :). hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

```
 <script>
var PrintMail = function () {

            window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("printArea").innerHTML;
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();

        };
    </script>

   <div id="printArea">
    Content that you want to print
   </div>



  <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank">
  </iframe>
```